# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.NettyServer

Tags: scala, sbt, play-slick

I am trying to add play-slick to my project, when I refresh my sbt I get no errors but in compile time it breaks with this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.NettyServer`. I've tried multiple fixes found on the internet but none of them worked for me. This is my sbt:

```
name := "TwoKingsSite"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val `twokingssite` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache ,
  ws,
  filters,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.0")

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```